# FadeIn and FadeOut when dynamically loading with php

Tags: php, jquery

I want to fadeOut the current big picture in the #inner_left div by clicking one of the thumb pics in the #photo1 div.The thumb images are loaded with php.Currently the loading of the pictures works on click normally but I want them to fadeout and fadeIn when clicked on the next thumb.For now this is what I have in my jquery part..

```
$('#photo1 img').click(function(){


$('#inner_left img').attr('src',$(this).attr('big'));   });
```

and the php part which loads the thumbs:

```
 foreach($imagess as $image){
    if($image['image_th_source'] != '' && $image['image_source'] != ''){
        echo '
            <div id=photo1>
               <a href="#"> <img src="'.$image['image_th_source'].'" alt="'.$image['image_alt'].'" title="'.$image['image_title'].'" big="'.$image['image_source'].'" /></a>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

please help if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fading was solved like this after all:

```
$('.photo1 img').click(function(){
var our_photo =$(this);
$('#inner_left').fadeOut(1500, function(){
    $('#inner_left img').attr('src',our_photo.attr('big'));
    $('#inner_left').fadeIn(1500);

});});
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use the id attribute in photo1 inside the foreach iterator, try using classes (or changing the id in every div, every id should be unique).

you can then do this in your jQuery script

```
$('.photo1').click(function(){
    $('#inner_left').fadeOut();
    $('#inner_left').attr('src',$(this).attr('big'));
    $('#inner_left').fadeIn();
});
```

you may want to preload those images to get a clean effect tho